# Inputting a number beyond a range set by an array, index out of range error

Tags: c#, arrays, runtime-error

I want to make a program wherein a user inputs a number, in this case a number of items.
The number of items is then compared to a value in the array, and the corresponding discount is displayed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SIZE = 4;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int itemsbought = 0;
            int discountItem = 0;
            int[] items = new int[SIZE] { 0, 10, 26, 61 };
            int[] discount = new int[SIZE] { 0, 5, 10,15 };

            InputItems(ref itemsbought);
            getDiscount(items, discount, ref itemsbought, ref discountItem);

            Console.WriteLine("Your discount is {0}", discountItem);

        }

        private static void getDiscount(int[] items, int[] discount, ref int itemsbought, ref int discountItem)
        {
            int idx = 0;
            for (idx = 0; itemsbought > items[idx] || idx > items.Length; idx++)
            {

                    discountItem = discount[idx];
            }
            }

        private static void InputItems(ref int itemsbought)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of items you bought");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemsbought))
                if (itemsbought < 0) 
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, whole numbers over 0 only");
            }
                Console.WriteLine("Error, whole numbers over 0 only");
        }
    }
}
```

When a number above 61 is entered I get the "Index out of range" error.  How can I make is so that if a number above 61 is entered, it displays 15?  Also how can I do it so that this boundary includes 61 and over instead of 61 giving an output of 10?

Also everytime I enter something it gives the error message shown displays only when a number is less than 0 or a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the small error you made, see this corrected version:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < items.Length && itemsbought > items[idx]; idx++)
```

There are three important changes:

1. idx > items.Length is always false. And idx= items.Length is out-of-range.
2. Use && instead of || remember if this condition is true, the loop continued execution, as soon as it is false once, execution is stopped.
3. exchanged the order. You must check idx < items.Length **before** accessing items[idx]. The shortcircuit && evaluates from left to right and stops if the result is determined.

So your corrected code will look like this:

```
private static void getDiscount(int[] items, int[] discount, int itemsbought, ref int discountItem)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for (idx = 0; idx < items.Length && itemsbought > items[idx]; idx++)
        discountItem = discount[idx];
}
```

But I'd prefer to put the condition inside the loop to make it more readable:

```
private static void getDiscount(int[] items, int[] discount, int itemsbought, ref int discountItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        if(itemsbought > items[i])
            discountItem = discount[i];
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

---

To address your other issue

> Also everytime I enter something it gives the error message shown displays only when a number is less than 0 or a double.

Reformat your code properly, one message output is in the right place, the other one is always executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your `getDiscount` as follows:

```
private static void getDiscount(int[] items, int[] discount, ref int itemsbought, ref int discountItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; itemsbought > items[i];)
    {
        discountItem = discount[i];
        i++;
        if (i >= items.Length)//will return the last element in the discount array(15)
            break;
    }
}
```

The reason you get the error is because a number > than 61 is not contained within your items array, so the for loop continues, you can break out of it to return the last element in the discount array (15)

Then rewrite your `InputItems` method like so:

```
private static void InputItems(int itemsbought)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of items you bought");
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemsbought) || itemsbought < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, whole numbers over 0 only");
    }
}
```

You return the same error message regardless of whether the tryparse/if statement succeeds or not. You will also need to update the call to `InputItems(itemsbought);`

Answer (score 0):

Different way of looking at your problem but you may choose to use it.

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item(string name, int qty)
        {
            ItemName = name;
            Qty = qty;
        }

        public enum DiscountRate
        {
            ZeroPercent = 0,
            FivePercent = 10,
            TenPercent = 26,
            FifteenPercent = 61

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Items Name: {0} | Units: {1} | Discount Rate: {2}", this.ItemName, this.Qty, this.Rate.ToString() );
        }

        public string CalculateDiscount()
        {
            if (this.Qty >= (int)DiscountRate.FifteenPercent)
            {
                this.Rate = DiscountRate.FifteenPercent;
                return this.ToString();
            }
            else if (this.Qty >= (int)DiscountRate.TenPercent && this.Qty < (int)DiscountRate.FifteenPercent)
            {
                this.Rate = DiscountRate.TenPercent;
                return this.ToString();
            }
            else if (this.Qty < (int)DiscountRate.TenPercent && this.Qty > 9)
            {
                this.Rate = DiscountRate.FivePercent;
                return this.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Rate = DiscountRate.ZeroPercent;
                return this.ToString();
            }
        }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public DiscountRate Rate {get; set;}
    }
```

Main Code:-

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Item a = new Item("Tennis Ball", 100);
            Item b = new Item("Spoon", 10);
            Item c = new Item("Candles", 27);
            Item d = new Item("Battery's", 2);
            Item e = new Item("Nails", 10);
            Item f = new Item("Marbles", 0);

            Console.WriteLine(a.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(b.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(c.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(d.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(e.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(f.CalculateDiscount());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```